# React-Leaflet Map relocation with using Places Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, leaflet, react-leaflet

My react application has map created with react Leaflet:

```
import {MapContainer TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
return (
<MapContainer
                center={[49.1951, 16.6068]}
                zoom={13}
                scrollWheelZoom={false}
            >
<TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />

</MapContainer>

<Search/>
);}
```

Also, my App has Search component that uses Places autocomplete, from which I can get new coordinates, it is here: https://github.com/AlonaVa/searchApp/blob/main/search.js

My task is to relocate my Map to the chosen position from search component (latLng).
Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map variable and a coordinates variable in the App comp.

then pass the setter for coordinates down to Search comp. Once the coordinates change trigger the map view change on the app

```
export default function App() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({ lat: "", lng: "" });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map && coordinates.lat && coordinates.lng) map.setView(coordinates);
  }, [map, coordinates]);

  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer
        center={[49.1951, 16.6068]}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
        whenCreated={setMap}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
      </MapContainer>
      <Search setCoordinates={setCoordinates} />
    </>
  );
}
```

In the Search comp if we take into account that value is an object that contains `lat` and `lng` inside use the coordinates setter to change the coordinates value:

```
 export default function Search({ coordinates, setCoordinates }) {
      const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
    
      const handleSelect = async (value) => {
        const results = await geocodeByAddress(value);
        latLng = await getLatLng(results[0]);
        setAddress(value);
        setCoordinates({ lat: value.lat, lng: value.lng });
      };
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks good, but my code is a little bit complicated and I already have declared whenCreated in my MapContainer: 
whenCreated={(map) => setBbox(map.getBounds())}
Can I add one more?

Comment: You can do this to combine both: `whenCreated={(map) => { setBbox(map.getBounds()); setMap(map) }}`

Comment: Good idea, thank you very much for your help!